# Appcelerator Android Packaging Failed

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-android

Getting what appears to be a simple error and I have no idea how to resolve it:

```
res/drawable/DefaultIcon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

The *problem* with the error is apparent. DefaultIcon.png is already alphabetical. How do I resolve this strange bug so I can package my app for the app store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regular expression tells that you have to use only lower-case alphabets, or 0-9 digits, or an underscore or a period (.).

Change the filename to all lowercases like **defaulticon.png** & it will work.

When I used a file name as **DefaultIcon.png**, I got the same error.

Then I renamed that file to all lower-cases alphabets & it worked fine.[image]

Comment: That was really it. They couldn't just say that haha. Thanks a million.

Comment: Well they said it all on console in that regex [a-z0-9_.]........ we just need to carefully look at every info.. 99% problems are solved by carefully looking at console messages :)

Comment: After hours of coding anyone would forget that a-z is not the same as A-Z and I'm glad someone caught it.